# Getting code inside the Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY code/* /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 3000
VOLUME /usr/src/app/
```

And my Docker Compose file:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  my_service:
    build: .   
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8102:3000
    working_dir: /usr/src/app/
    command: node src/app.js
    restart: always
```

When I make the build:

```
docker-compose build

Building api_core
Step 1 : FROM node:4
 ---> 93b396996a16
Step 2 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e1ee4fd2245d
Step 3 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8824a653a9e4
Step 4 : COPY code/* /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e4ee9901369
Step 5 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0e10126e1651
Step 6 : VOLUME /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c1f9d36d91bc
Successfully built c1f9d36d91bc
```

And when I run I got this error:

```
docker-compose up 

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/src/app.js
```

So Docker is telling me that it haven't found the app.js, so it is like the COPY was not working !

Comment: Have you tried running the docker image you created and checking if this path exists?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you copy your app inside your docker image.

But in your docker compose section, you mount `- ./app:/usr/src/app` so everything that is in your "./app" folder (on your host) is mounted in the docker container at /usr/src/app so what you copied in your dockerfile is overriden by the mount point.

Comment: By using this I would like to mount the code to an external storage. How could I do then ?

Comment: You have some options, one could be to put the data in a folder (/usr/src/originalapp) and cp /usr/src/originalapp /usr/src/app if /usr/src/app is empty

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly specifying a volume mapping in your compose file:

```
volumes:
  - ./app:/usr/src/app
```

This will override what you have previously specify in the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY code/* /usr/src/app/
```

Both statement may provide different results depending on where you have built the image and where you will start the container. You should check that what is mapped with your compose file gives the same result.